# Filtering a where query

Tags: c#, sql

I have i minor problem in my where-query. I have a textfile that contains different dates. I have managed to read all of this and I want to use the dates in different month.
The input format of the date in the textfile looks like this: 20130101.

My question: is there any way to look at index 4 and 5 and say that for month January index 4 should be 0 and index 5 should be 1? Or can i solve this in another way?

I have solved it like this for the moment but then my program will not work in the year of 2014..

```
if(ComboBoxMonth.Text == "January")
{
var query = from p in list
where p.Datum.StartsWith("201301")
select p;           
}
```

Comment: Is your question how do I go from a Text format of "January" to a format of MM = 01?

Comment: I have a combobox with all the month listed. When i click for example January in the combobox I want to see (from the textfile) if 20130101 matches january.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, I revert to the dot notation as I can visualize it better for some reason :)

```
list.Select(p=>p.Datum.Length >= 6 && p.Datum.SubString(4,2) == "01");
```

but, you could just do the same by using:

```
where p.Datum.Length >= 6 && p.Datum.SubString(4,2) == "01"
```

However, re-reading your question, maybe what you really want is just to convert to datetime and check any part of the date?

```
list.Select(p=>DateTime.ParseExact(p.Datum, "yyyyMMdd", null).Month == 1);
```

Comment: I don't think that is what the OP is asking, but then again it isn't very clear.

Comment: You might be right...I will leave this for now as it kind of seems what the OP is asking...and I will modify if not

Comment: I think you mean `Where`, not `Select`.

Comment: No, I mean `Select`. In this case they are pretty much equivalent. You could use a Where just the same

Comment: I think you've got the right idea.  He's looking to see if entries in the file start with 20XX01 for the month of January, 20XX02 for February, etc, without having to hard code the year into his logic.  Substring is the way to go.

Comment: I added an alternative for checking any part of the date object using DateTime instead of string functions. Just in case the OP meant that instead.

Comment: Yeah substring is what i want to use! but i got an error when running my program "ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled" "Index and length must refer to a location within the string."
What I want to do is what Maurice Reeves said.

Comment: You have to check the length in that case. I have updated my code

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the input into a DateTime and filter off that with this code:

```
if(ComboBoxMonth.Text == "January")
{
    var query = from p in list
    select new DateTime(p.Substring(0, 4), p.Substring(4, 2), p.Substring(6, 2)) into y
    where y.Month == 1
    select new { Input = p, DateValue = y }          
}
```

Comment: Why not use ParseExact? It is more explicit and probably more efficient (I have not verified that)

Comment: @JustinPihony That works too, I just happened to use the Substring method when I wrote the example

Answer (score 0):

```
where DateTime.ParseExact(p.Datum, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month == 1
```

Comment: this is assuming your dates will always be correctly formatted.  you'll want to take other steps to DateTime.TryParse if you aren't positive it will be.

Answer (score -1):

If your question is how do you go from *January* to 01 you could use [`System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.MonthNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthnames.aspx) to look up the month index

```
// +1 to make it 1 based
string twoDigitMonth = (Array.IndexOf(System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.MonthNames, ComboBoxMonth.Text)) + 1).ToString("D2"); 

var query = from p in list
where p.Datum.Substring(4,2)==twoDigitMonth 
select p;
```

Comment: Can someone please explain the -1 so I can update my answer accordingly.  Thanks